# Visual Studio .Net source stepping for System.Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to step through some of the .Net source in System.Linq (specifically System.Linq.Enumerable.cs) and have followed a few existing guides for stepping through .Net source:

[How can I step into Microsoft's .NET framework source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186080/how-can-i-step-into-microsofts-net-framework-source-code)

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sburke/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mcsuksoldev/2010/09/09/debugging-the-net-framework-source-code/

But so far nothing is working. I have disabled 'Just My Code' and enabled '.Net source stepping' in VS 2015. Its shows modules loaded for mscorelib.dll and System.Core.dll but System.Linq.dll is unable to load symbols.

Comment: .NET 4.6.2 is still not GDR, should happen soon.  Use the troubleshooting procedure shown in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27655501/17034) to get a fact instead of a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your troubles might be caused by the nature of LINQ itself.

Debugging LINQ has some major restrictions:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385795.aspx

For example:

> **LINQ to SQL**
>
> When you are debugging LINQ code, stepping has some
>   behavioral differences you should know about.
>
> In LINQ to SQL queries, the predicate code is beyond the control of
>   the debugger. Therefore, you cannot step into the predicate code. Any
>   query that compiles to an expression tree produces code that is beyond
>   the control of the debugger.

Comment: Hmm quite possible, but surely that would not cause the module to be unable to load? Also I am trying to step into Enumerable.Contains, which doesn't take a predicate (or any delegate).